# How to setup tinyproxy on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, chromium, settings

I have bought a Raspberry Pi for one of my children and they are using it as a basic desktop computer.  I would like to setup whitelist filtering on the Pi.  For various reasons I won't be able to setup a separate Pi as a proxy.  Instead I would like to configure the Pi directly to run web filtering software such as tinyproxy on itself.

My son's account has sudo access but it has been set to automatically request sudo password whenever sudo is run and the sudo password has been changed to be different from his account login.

Steps I have taken so far have been from this tutorial site

- installed tinyproxy
- I then edited the config file to listen on 127.0.0.1
- I also set allow for localhost
- I then added additional lines to the config file to enable whitelist
  FilterExtended On
  FilterURLs On
  FilterDefaultDeny Yes
  Filter "/etc/tinyproxy/whitelist"
- I then saved the config file - set up the whitelist file using the suggested address format for sites I wish to allow
  twitter.com

  - I started the service
    sudo /etc/init.d/tinyproxy start
  - I even used the following to tell chromium to hopefully use tiny proxy
    chromium-browser --proxy-server="tinyproxy:8080"

Despite this chromium still allows access to any sites.  What am I missing in settings this up?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured part of the Stack Exchange Network - I wonder whether you will have to include us in your black-list! I think you are misunderstanding `sudo` when you say "and the sudo password has been changed to be different from his account login."  Sudo allows users who are included in its configuration file {be very very carefully when editing that as it is possible to lock everyone out of the system with that, best use `sudoedit`which tries to prevent mistakes that could breaking things} to give ___their___ password to do commands that would normally need...

Comment: ... to be done as the superuser, the `root` account. You might get a better idea of what it does with this Unix & Linux SE question: "[Changing root password does not change sudo password](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66293/changing-root-password-does-not-change-sudo-password)".

Comment: Whether I understand what sudo does or not I have managed to change the sudo password on my sons account to be different from his account password so he can learn about how to use sudo but he is still reliant on me entering the sudo password for him so that I can check he is not going to do anything wrong. Having said that I am still keen to see if anyone can help me with regard to the actual point of my question which is how to setup tinyproxy and the issues I was having there.

Comment: This appears to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You have **decided** `tinyproxy` is the solution and are asking us to debug your solution.

Comment: Hi Milliways - tried and failed badly with dansguardian - squid I didn't even understand to be able to get it setup. I thought it would be better to get to the point and focus on tiny proxy which looks like the best chance of success. I also thought it would be a good idea (and surely the point of this site) to show what I have attempted instead of asking someone to essence do it all for me.